# Pass variables after form submitted

Tags: python, post, amazon-s3

I have a post form that calls Amazon's S3 service. I am doing a direct from browser upload to amazon, and thus have to pass some additional information to Amazon, that I will not know until the file is uploaded (file-type, name, 'signature' which references both). http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

It is a large video file, which I don't want to upload to my server first, which (to the best of my knowledge) rules out using `urllib2.open(...)` to pass the additional variables to amazon as a POST request. I've been working at it for a couple days now, and haven't had any success with it. What would be the best way to do this?

Note: I will probably be using the uploadify plugin to upload the file. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how S3 handles this, but there's no access to Azure blobs without private keys. If you want your user to upload directly to a blob, are you planning to expose your private keys as part of the form? **This sounds like a bad idea™** This may not be applicabble for S3, again...

Comment: Well, you pass an encrypted signature, which contains among other things, the secret passkey, but I wouldn't care if anyone saw that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Query String Request Authentication Alternative.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth)

> You can authenticate certain types of requests by passing the required
>   information as query-string parameters instead of using the
>   Authorization HTTP header. This is useful for enabling direct
>   third-party browser access to your private Amazon S3 data, without
>   proxying the request. The idea is to construct a "pre-signed" request
>   and encode it as a URL that an end-user's browser can retrieve.
>   Additionally, you can limit a pre-signed request by specifying an
>   expiration time.